# Linux only gives option to install to USB, not to computer

Tags: linux, system-installation

Normally when I'd install Linux it was simply creating a bootable USB and installing from it.

However, I'm trying to do that on my Dell XPS 15 and dual boot Windows 10 and Elementary OS (also tried Linux Mint). The issue seems to be when I try to run the installer and it stops me after choosing Wi-Fi saying that my computer only has 2GB and needs 8GB. It's trying to install on my USB drive and isn't giving me an option to install on my laptop.

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a driver. Depending on your distro, you'ld find stuff like 'non-free' images embedding more drivers, ... Not familiar with your device though. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

It ended up I had forgotten to enable Legacy mode and after doing that it worked.